# Model Issue is not working

Tags: python, django

I am following a tutorial and trying to make a website sort of like stack overflow that allows people to post their issues. But for right now, the issue I just created is not showing on my HTML page,for other HTML elements worked fine. I set 'DEBUG=True' on setting.py, but I did not get any feedback. I suppose something wrong with my HTML page or maybe models.py. But I could not figure it out why. Could anyone help?

models.py

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('published','Published'),
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9,choices= STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Issue,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:issue_detail',args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

view.py

```
def list_of_issue(request):
    issue = Issue.objects.filter(status='published')
    paginator = Paginator(issue,10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        issues = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        issues = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        issues = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)            
    template = 'blog/issue/list_of_issue.html'
    return render(request,template,{'issues':issues,'page':page})
```

list_of_issue.html

```
{% extends 'blog/issue/base.html' %}

{% block description %}This is the description{% endblock %}
{% block title %}List of blog Issue{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="page-header"><h1>Our lastest issues</h1></div>
            <button class="btn btn-default"><a href="{% url 'blog:new_issue'%}">New issues</a></button>
     {% for Issue in Issues %}
         <h2><a href="{{Issue.get_absolute_url}}">{{ Issue.title }}</a></h2>
         <small>Written by {{ Issue.author }} on {{ Issue.published}} in <a href="{{Issue.project.get_absolute_url}}">{{Issue.project}}</a></small>
         <hr>
         {{ Issue.content | truncatewords:40 | linebreaks}}
     {% endfor %}
     {% include 'blog/paginator.html' with page=Issues%}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="page-header">
     <h1>Use info/project info</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>     
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you set `DEBUG=True`, in the `settings.py`, do you get any feedback what is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if this queryset is not empty? `issue = Issue.objects.filter(status='published')`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did not get feedback actually. just nothing shows on my screen

Comment: @HåkenLid yes. I added new issue. But it does not show on html page

Comment: There's not enough information for us to give you an answer. Create a minimal example [mcve]. The bug could be in `base.html` or some other place. "does not show" doesn't give us any clue to what's happening here. Maybe the parent template doesn't have a `block content` ?

Comment: When you say not working, what are you seeing in your when you load your project, obviously not working doesn't mean nothing appears, you see a blank page, or 403 page, something like that

Comment: @Lemayzeur Sorry for the unclear. the issue I just created is not showing on my HTML page,for other HTML elements worked fine.

Comment: can you try to `print(issue)` after this line `issue = Issue.objects.filter(status='published')` to see whether the queryset is not empty?

Comment: In your view, you have "issues" in lower case in the context but in your view, you have it in caps - "Issues".

Comment: @butteredtoast i believe you have typo. Can you say it more clear?

Comment: @Sue-MayXu change either one of **`issues`** in `return render(request,template,{'issues':issues,'page':page})` to **`Issues`** or in your template, change **`Issues`** in `{% for Issue in Issues %}` to **`issues`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a typo in your HTML template, Here is what your return in your with the context `issues`, **Note all letters are lower case**

```
return render(request,template,{'issues':issues,'page':page})
```

Whereas in your templates, you iterate over `Issues` with a capital letter.

```
{% for Issue in Issues %}
```

Change it to

```
{% for Issue in issues %}
```

I also suggest that you rename the variable `issue` to `issues`:

```
def list_of_issue(request):
    issue issues = Issue.objects.filter(status='published')
    paginator = Paginator(issue,10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        issues = paginator.page(page)
    # rest of the code
```

That's because you don't want pagination, to avoid `NameError`, the queryset will always `issues` as it's the name being sent to template here `{'issues':issues,'page':page}`